# Anglesharp and Xamarin.Forms OpenAsync does not work in.Droid project

Tags: android, xamarin, web-scraping, anglesharp

I currently have an application for Android in Java, which I`am rewriting in Xamarin.Forms for the iOS support. In the Android app i used Jsoup, and in the Xamarin app i am using AngleSharp.

I have the issue that the code below works on iOS and UWP, but not in the Droid project.

My suspicion is that no connection is being made when calling context.OpenAsync(url);

I have the

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in my Android Manifest. I am targeting minSdk=17, targetSdk=24.
The issue persisists in both the Emulator and on my Galaxy S7.

Code:

```c#
try
        {
                var url = "<URL>";
                var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
                var context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
                var document = await context.OpenAsync(url);
                IHtmlInputElement username = document.QuerySelector("input[id='username']") as IHtmlInputElement;
                IHtmlInputElement password = document.QuerySelector("input[id='password']") as IHtmlInputElement;
                IHtmlFormElement loginform = document.QuerySelector("form[id='logonForm']") as IHtmlFormElement;

                username.Value = "<uname>";
                password.Value = "<pword>";
                document = await loginform.SubmitAsync();

                Debug.WriteLine(context.Active.Url);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR " + e);
            }
```

Nb. Due to privacy i am not showing the url or the username and password.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Exception / Stack Trace ?

Comment: None, except the fact that the username.Value gives an ERROR System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Which is correct, because there are no elements defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with AngleSharp, but rather with the Mono stack below. Make sure you have given the app the necessary permissions. Also make sure that potential certificates (if the page is accessed via HTTPS) are accepted. Android will deny requests that do not fit the permission model (e.g., app does not have permission, self-signed certificates that are not installed, ...).

Hope this helps! (unfortunately, the exact issue for the question was never found / communicated - see [corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/466)).